# How to get the metrics for a resource using its resource ARN in AWS using aws-go-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have a resource ARN of a resource in AWS (eg ec2 instance). I want to get the list of the metrics for this particular resource in Go. How do I get it?

Comment: Metrics may change depending on the type of AWS resource. Can you be more specific?

Comment: currently i am looking for ec2 . But in general is there a way i can get list of all the metrics available for this resource providing that i have a resource ARN of that resource ??.

Comment: I am afraid that EC2 service does not expose metrics _per se_. CloudWatch is what you are looking for probably: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/working_with_metrics.html.

Comment: yes i know EC2 itself does not expose any metrics . i want to know if their is some api method which takes this resource ARN as input and gives list of metrics as output for that resource.???